Docker@v2 cannot push to ghcr (access denied)
Docker@v2 push fails to push image to ghcr.io. Login to ghcr works with the same service connection. The same pipeline works without problems with a service connection to Docker Hub. The PAT used in the ghcr service connection works when pushing from a command line. Tried pushing to repo-less package, package connected to a repo, and multiple organizations including one where I am admin. PAT has write:packages access rights.
Output:

2024-11-06T07:18:53.5923641Z The push refers to repository [ghcr.io/my-github-org/my-repo]
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6754212Z ead24dff829c: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6754669Z 5f70bf18a086: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6754950Z bff24fa5ba6d: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6755208Z 734661639d51: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6755464Z 008aac071916: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6755784Z 261abc8281b7: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6756033Z 7794e8d8212d: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6756282Z ceffe60ed721: Preparing
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6756529Z 261abc8281b7: Waiting
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6756777Z 7794e8d8212d: Waiting
2024-11-06T07:18:53.6757020Z ceffe60ed721: Waiting
2024-11-06T07:18:53.8064164Z denied: denied
2024-11-06T07:18:53.8071559Z
2024-11-06T07:18:53.8100848Z ##[error]denied: denied
2024-11-06T07:18:53.8205302Z ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
2024-11-06T07:18:53.8277688Z ##[section]Finishing: Push an image

Pipeline yaml:

# Docker
# Build a Docker image
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - feat/k8s-test-env

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feat/k8s-test-env

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  tag: "$(Build.BuildId)"

stages:
  - stage: BuildandPush
    displayName: Build image and push to ghcr.io
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build an image
            inputs:
              command: build
              dockerfile: "**/Dockerfile"
              containerRegistry: ghcr-io
              repository: my-github-organization/my-repo
              tags: |
                test1$(tag)
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Push an image
            inputs:
              command: push
              containerRegistry: ghcr-io
              repository: my-github-organization/my-repo
              tags: |
                test1-$(tag)

My service connection for ghcr:


Hi, can you please try to run the docker commands locally using your personal access token to see if it works. You can refer the commands in the document Authenticating with a personal access token (classic). This is to narrow down if the issue is related to the azure devops pipeline or the personal access token scope.

As stated in the question: "The PAT used in the ghcr service connection works when pushing from a command line." So yes, it works locally. So it's not the token itself or its scope, it's definitely something in the pipeline or the task.

Thanks for your reply. In this case, please try to use the PAT in the pipeline with a script task instead of the docker task with a service connection. If this works, then the issue may relate to the task or the service connection. You can also create a new service connection and try again.

I ended up deploying a container registry in my kubernetes cluster using docker.io/registry

Try login into the container registry before building and pushing the image.
Example:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to container registry
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: ghcr-io

# build and push tasks here

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Logout from container registry
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    command: logout
    containerRegistry: ghcr-io

See the examples for more details.

I've tried. The login task works, but the push still does not...
